# Use libfido2 on macos to set PIN on usb security token

Tags: macos, devices, usb-device, fido-u2f

I have bought a FIDO-U2F/FIDO2 usb security token and managed to add it as passkey for github on my macOS (sonoma).

It didn't work for another site and I suspect that it's because the key doesn't have a PIN yet.

It is possible to set the key PIN with the fido2-token command provided with libfido2 that can be installed with brew on macOS.

But it requires a device name as argument and I don't know what device name to use. On linux we have to add a user device and the key seller gives the recipe to do so, but they don't provide any info for macOS.

Windows provide a GUI interface in the system parameters to set the key PIN, but I would prefer avoiding to use a Window machine to do this.

**EDIT 1**: Since I posted the question, I found out that you can see the connected usb devices by go into Apple icon > About This Mac > More Info > System Report > USB. The path might be slightly different in your version.

I do see the key listed there, as I did see it too with lsusb installed with brew, but it doesn't show the /dev I could use to talk to it.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research I found the solution.

With libfido2 installed with brew, we can list the FIDO2 security tokens (e.g. usb keys), with the command `fido2-token -L`. It gives the device to use for other commands.

The manuals for the libfido2 commands and especially the fido2-token command is available here: https://developers.yubico.com/libfido2/Manuals/fido2-token.html.

```bash
$ fido2-token -L
ioreg://4295015862: vendor=0x1e0d, product=0xf1d0 (NEOWAVE NEOWAVE Winkeo FIDO2)

$ fido2-token -I ioreg://4295015862
proto: 0x02
major: 0x01
minor: 0x00
build: 0x00
caps: 0x05 (wink, cbor, msg)
version strings: U2F_V2, FIDO_2_0
extension strings: hmac-secret
aaguid: 3789da91f94346bc95c350ea2012f03a
options: rk, up, noplat, noclientPin
fwversion: 0x0
maxmsgsiz: 2048
maxcredcntlst: 0
maxcredlen: 0
maxlargeblob: 0
pin protocols: 1
pin retries: undefined
pin change required: false
uv retries: undefined
```

As can be seen with the `noclientPin`, the key PIN is currently not set.

I then set the key PIN

```bash
$ fido2-token -S ioreg://4295015862
Enter new PIN for ioreg://4295015862: 
Enter the same PIN again: 

$ fido2-token -I ioreg://4295015862
proto: 0x02
major: 0x01
minor: 0x00
build: 0x00
caps: 0x05 (wink, cbor, msg)
version strings: U2F_V2, FIDO_2_0
extension strings: hmac-secret
aaguid: 3789da91f94346bc95c350ea2012f03a
options: rk, up, noplat, clientPin
fwversion: 0x0
maxmsgsiz: 2048
maxcredcntlst: 0
maxcredlen: 0
maxlargeblob: 0
pin protocols: 1
pin retries: 8
pin change required: false
uv retries: undefined
```

As we can see the key PIN is now set.